# How to display month formula in header in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I display this month formula that I have in the detail section to print in the report header. It prints blank in the report header =

If ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {?Datedeb}), 'MMM yy')= ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {fielddate}), 'MMM yy') then left(MonthName(Month({fielddate})),3)

Answer (score 0):

A formula in the report header uses data from the 1st record in the report. 
In your case, the first record in the report probably fails the formula condition and hence returns nothing.
So either change the condition or sort/filter the records to ensure the first row in the report contains data that matches your expectation.

Comment: Thank you. I also discovered that this was the reason. I subsequently changed my formulas to ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {?Datedeb}), 'MMM yy') and just changed the number after 'm' for each month's formula . It is working now 100%